# onTouchlistner on translate animation imageView in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-event

### The onTouchlistner is not working on translate animated imageview. the actually view is not moved during the animation(where only copy of the image is animated).Please let me know how can add the touchevent to the animating image view. please find below the code for the same.

```
                **activity class**


  public class AnimationAndroid extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                ImageView viewOne; /* image view */
                Animation aOne;
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    viewOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewone); /* to get image view */
                    aOne = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animatextone);   /* initializing the animation from xml file */
                    viewOne.setOnTouchListener(this); /* onTouch listner on imageView */
                    viewOne.startAnimation(aOne); /* to start animation */
                }

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
/* onTouch event function*/
                      Toast.makeText(AnimationAndroid.this, "Image One",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); /* to display the toast message on touch */
                }
         }


                **Animation xml file code** 




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shareInterpolator="false">
               <translate
                android:fromXDelta="20%p"
                android:fromYDelta="20%p"
                android:duration="28000"
                android:repeatMode="reverse"
                android:repeatCount="infinite"
                android:toXDelta="28%p"
                android:toYDelta="18%p" 
                android:fillAfter="false"   
                />
            </set>

        Please let me know how i can resolve the issue. I need to have infinite
        animation.still onClick on the animated image is not working.
```

---

```
        **animation using nineoldandroid library**

       Implementation using nineoldandroid library but still not able to succeed.
       The click on animated moving image is not triggering the event.
       Please let me if am going wrong in implementing the nanooldandroid library   



public class NineOldTesting extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
       /* Called when the activity is first created. */
       final int duration = 2 * 15000;  /* duration of animation */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           ImageView tv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testView); /* imageview id*/
           AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();   /* to do animation together */
           set.playTogether(
               ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv, "translationX", 0, 90),
               ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv, "translationY", 0, 90)
           ); /* to move image in x and y direction */
           set.setDuration(duration);  /*  to set duration of animation */
           set.start(); /* start animation */
           tv.setOnClickListener(this);  /* setting onclick listner for image view*/
       }
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           /* TODO Auto-generated method stub */
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); /* to display toast message on click*/
       }
   }
```

Comment: View Animation can't move View actually,instead you should use Property Animation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: I need to support for android api level 7, where property animation is not there. any other way to overcome this issue

Comment: i tried with the nineoldandroid library still not able succeed.please find code below.